# Why are button transition animations not resetting to normal position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I mouseover button it works fine. But when I clicked and enter inside the credits scene and came back the default width of the credits button changed and not reset to normal position.

It should return to normal position whenever if I clicked the button and enters into any scene and return to the current scene.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share related code. Without those it is not understandable.

Comment: I am using Unity's button build in transition component and when I hover over the button I am highlighting the animation. So I am not writing any code to control for the animation since I only have a scene change transition code. So I don't know whether I need to have a control for that. Since it is single frame animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having long conversation, this is the summary and solution.
Naveen was using Unity's default animation transitions for buttons.
As, he only needed highlighted transition, he only added that animation which scales the button. But, no animation was added for the normal state. As a result, when he was switching the canvas, the scale of the button was already increased and stayed there.

There can be multiple solutions, but here's mine.
Just add keyframes in normal state, which keeps the button in normal scale.